# Is uniform distribution on unit sphere subgaussian?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Is uniform distribution on unit sphere subgaussian?

To be specific, let $X = (X_1,\dots,X_d) \sim \mbox{Unif}(\mathcal{S}^{d-1})$. What is the Orlicz-$\psi_2$ norm of $X$?

Comment: Is there something to this question that I'm missing?  $X$ is bounded, so of course it is sub-Gaussian.  Indeed, $|X|=1$ surely so the Orlicz $\psi_2$ norm, as defined on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Gaussian_random_variable, appears to be $(\ln 2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks. i think it is just direct computation but i found it troublesome to find the right number.